# Alignment Issue in C Code - Printing a Star Pattern

Tags: c, function, escaping

I'm working on a C program where I want to print a star pattern with aligned stars based on user input. However, I'm facing issues with the alignment, specifically when using the '\t' (tab) character. I would appreciate some guidance on how to achieve the desired output.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Ages for 3 people
    int age1, age2, age3;

    // Getting all 3 users' ages
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("Enter your age below: \n");
        if (j == 0) {
            scanf("%d", &age1);
        } else if (j == 1) {
            scanf("%d", &age2);
        } else {
            scanf("%d", &age3);
        }
    }

    // Printing a star with each age and a message
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("John:%d***\n", age1);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            printf("Itachi:%d***\n", age2);
        } else {
            printf("Bob:%d****\n", age3);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm looking for advice on how to use \t to align the stars appropriately.

Comment: What is the ***expected*** output for a particular input? What is this program supposed to do?

Comment: Don't use 3 variables and all those `if` statements. Just make an array so you can use `age[i]`.

Comment: Tab will always be unreliable. Use spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use a field width in the `printf()` statements for alignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Ages for 3 people
    int age[3];
    char *names[] = {"John", "Itachi", "Bob"};

    // Getting all 3 users' ages
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("Enter %s's age below: \n", names[j]);
        scanf("%d", &age[j]);
    }

    // Printing a star with each age and a message
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%-10s%3d***\n", names[i], age[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A further exercise for the OP would be to get rid of the parallel arrays and create an array of three person structs.

Comment: @Chris I usually mention things like that myself, but since this question was just about formatting output I decided to keep the answer simple and targeted.

Comment: That's perfectly fair.